# .htaccess RedirectCond using previous RewriteCond variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Alright, so I've been at this for a bit now... But I've always been terrible with the RewriteEngine and I can't seem to find an easy answer for this scenario.

A couple of examples of what I'm trying to rewrite (using a wildcard subdomain):

```
static.example.com/js/test.js => /example.com/js/test.js
static.test.example.com/css/test.css => /test.example.com/css/test.css
```

However, I'm currently hitting the infamous redirect loop using the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

It works if I add a RewriteCond checking for a specific domain in the path... for example...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

But, obviously, that won't work for wildcard domains...

Is there a proper way of doing something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

It gives me a 500 error, so I don't think it's supported... Unfortunately, the server I'm using doesn't support the [END] flag, so I'm having to find a way around it... Or is it possible to do maybe something like the following?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^/%1/(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

I admit, the logic in that one seems a bit off...

I'm not sure where to look for the answer to this type of situation.. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can not use backrefrances (apache special variable)  in pattern of a RewriteCond. You can use `\n` variable instead of `%n` . The problem with using `%n` in RewriteCond's pattern is that Apache treats it as a plain text string not as a variable.

Comment: So, try doing something like 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\1' ?